# Android app on Chromebook: How to get rid of "this app may not work when resized" message?

Tags: android, chromebook, maximize-window

My Android app works on Chromebook and when maximizing the window it is running in, it properly resizes. Still, the Chromebook briefly shows up a popup message saying "this app may not work when resized". How do I suppress this message?

Comment: show your manifest

Comment: What is your target SDK level? Please show your build.gradle.

Comment: uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="14"     (for legal reasons I can't show my entire manifest.xml file)